# How to get position of letters in word

Tags: java

I need to get indexes of letters in word, for example:

SOMEWORDS|743295618

D - first letter(relatively to alphabet) in word, so _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 1 _ E - second - > _ _ _ 2 _ _ _ 1 _ M - third -> _ _ 3 2 _ _ _ 1 _ ... etc

STAR | 3412

LETTER | 314526

So, i need to write function on java that takes String and get back int with indexes or int array with this indexes!
Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Err, what? How do you obtain 743295618 from SOMEWORDS (assuming that's what your example is supposed to show)?

Comment: @JB Nizet D - first letter in word, so _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 1 _
E - second - > _ _ _ 2 _ _ _ 1 _
M - third -> _ _ 3 2 _ _ _ 1 _
... etc
It's very hard for me to describe that on english. Sorry Again!

Comment: @JB Nizet D - first letter relatively to alphabet order, yea, it is not  just first letter in word

Comment: R is before T in the latin alphabet, so it would have to be LETTER | 315624, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your alphabet and your words contains only uppercase ASCII letters, you can define it like this:

```
private static final int[] ALPHABET = [
    12, // A is at index 12
    7, // B is at index 7
    ...
    22 // Z is at index 22
}
```

Then you just need to iterator through each character of the string (you should be able to do that, or at least to figure it out using the String javadoc), and get the index of this character in the alphabet using

```
int index = ALPHABET[currentCharacter - 'A'];
```

For a more generic solution, you could define the alphabet as a `Map<Character, Integer>`, where the keys are all the characters of your alphabet, and the values are the index of the character in the alphabet.

You would then use

```
int index = ALPHABET.get(currentCharacter);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to go about the task (I just read the question again and discovered I probably misunderstood before, so updated this answer).

I think the easiest is a double loop. The outer loop takes each letter in the alphabet in turn. However, start declaring an `int` array the same lenght as the word. Also initialize a count of already numbered letters to 0. If using uppercase English letters, the outer loop can be `for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)`. The inner loop goes through your word one char at a time. If the char is the same as the alphabet letter, increment your counter and assign it into the position of the `int`array that corresponds to the position in the word. For example, when checking `LETTER` for `E`, you will encounter it at index 1 (0-based) and therefore put number 1 into index 1 of your array. You will encounter `E` again at index 4, increase the counter to 2 and assign this 2 into index 4 of the array. Once you’re done with the alphabet, all the cells of the array should have different numbers. If there is still a 0 left in the array, it’s because the word contained something that isn’t an uppercase English letter.

Typically, most alphabet letters are not in your word, so most times through the outer loop, nothing will happen. Don’t worry about this. Apart from this, the approach pretty much mimics the procedure you outlined in the question. It first fills in a 1 in the right place, then a 2 and so forth.

Another option is sorting the letters. But you still have to keep track of where they came from. So for this option, declare a class with two fields, the letter and its index in the original word. For each letter of the word, create an object of the class. Put all the objects into a list or array. `LETTER` will become something like `[L0, E1, T2, T3, E4, R5]` Sort the list or array by the letter. It’s probably easiest to have your class implement the `Comparable` interface (a `Comparator` is another option). Use a standard Java `sort` method like `Collections.sort()` or `List.sort()`. These are stable, that is, will not swap identical letters, so you can be sure that the list or array you had before will be sorted as `[E1, E4, L0, R5, T2, T3]`. Now loop through this list. For each object, add one to the index of the object and assign this sum into an `int` array (like before) in the index you get from the object. Examples: At index 0 you have E1, so put 0 + 1 (that is, 1) into `yourNumberArray[1]. At index 1 you have E4, so put 1 + 1 into`yourNumberArray[4]. This will give the same result as the first approach.

**Old answer**

The old answer would give you 214413 for `LETTER`. I believe now that you require 315624 with no duplicate numbers.

First step is to sort the letters of your word alphabetically to establish the order of them in the alphabet. This is eased by the fact that the natural order of letters agrees with the order in the English alphabet (if you need other alphabets, it’s a complication, but it can be done, not too hard). If you just sort all the letters, e.g., `LETTER` becomes `EELRTT`, the position in the sorted array does not correspond exactly to the order because of the duplicates.

To sort and get rid of duplicates at the same time, I suggest you use a `TreeSet<Character>`. Simply add all the letters of the word to the set, it will ignore duplicates. Take out the chars of the set into a `String` (you may use the set’s `stream` or its `iterator` method, they hand out the chars in the right order, and a `StringBuilder`). Use the string’s `indexOf(int)` method to determine the index of the char in the sorted string (just give the method a `char` no matter the the parameter has type `int`). Add 1 to the index because indices are 0-based and you need a 1-based number (you don’t want 203415 for `LETTER`, but 314526). That’s it.

I will leave the coding to you. Happy coding.